# Position of bootstrap modal window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

My modal window from boostrap with AngularJS always opens at the bottom of the window, not as an overlay.

Mark Up:

```
<div class ="ngView-Container" ng-view ng-controller="galleryController" >

    <div ng-controller="galleryController">
        <script type ="text/ng-template" id="overlay.html">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Modal </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="overlay">
                        <img ng-src={{photo}}>          
                    </div>

            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ok()">
                CLOSE
            </button>
    </div>


        </script>

</div>
```

I am using bootstrap UI for modal dialog

```
var myAppController = angular.module('myAppController',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

In my controller:

```
  $scope.open = function(arg){

            var modelInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: "overlay.html",
                scope: $scope,
                controller: "ModalInstanceCtrl",
                resolve : {
                        photo : function(){
                            return arg;
                        }
                },


            });


 myAppController.controller("ModalInstanceCtrl",function($scope, $modalInstance, photo){
            $scope.photo = photo;
            $scope.ok = function(){
                $modalInstance.close();
            }
        })
```

Additional question:
If I apply `position=fixed, top=0, left=0 to <div class="overlay>` which is inside `<div class= "modal-body">`, the overlay appears with top margin for some reason.

Comment: 1st thing why `ng-view ng-controller="galleryController" ` on pop div? inner content will get replaced by $routeProvider

Comment: I am building this on fly without full understanding of Angularjs (or MVC) due to time constraint. For some reason, the modal window content is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal
Its a pretty good plugin for all bootstrap/angular-sites imo

But if you wanna use your own, you should check that you dont have an conflicting CSS-styles and that the modal is not wrapped in some container(div or something) that forces a different position on it.

Comment: I believe I am using boostrap-ui. (I didn't include the code for dependecy in my post. )

Comment: That's great - but if the position of the modal is wrong, you might wanna look into your markup or mabye debug on the html/css to see if there's any other DOM element manipulating with your modals position or something like that - EDIT: mabye throw some of it on jsfiddle